# Choose default selected option after pressing reset botton

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="tool in phaseTools.tools">
   <select class="form-control" 
           ng-init="VMcpu=tool.deploymentType.VM.CPU[0]"             
           ng-model="VMcpu" 
           ng-options="item for item in tool.deploymentType.VM.CPU" 
           id="{{tool.name}}vm_cpu">
   </select>      
</div>

$scope.resett = function() {   
     $scope.VMcpu = $scope.selectedToolsInPhase[0]
                   .tools[0]
                   .deploymentType
                   .VM
                   .CPU[0];
}
```

I want to reset default value to value at index[0] using reset button 
enter code herebut its not getting reflected in drop down. i have update ng-model value here in controller under scope.reset.

Comment: What are values of `$scope.phaseTools` and `$scope.selectedToolsInPhase` ?

Comment: $scope.phaseTools and $scope.selectedToolsInPhase consists of json data in array format consisting of names and values for different tools.I am able to load dropdown correctly as tools values. Its just that when i select a dropdown down value and reset it to default value its not working.It is only working for the time when we don't select anything and press reset , reser is able to load default value in DropDown